# How to get the events related to an app with CFoundry

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry

I am using the library of CFoundry but I have a hard time to find the way to call the events associated to a specific app.

I have this:

```
app = client.app_by_name @appName

appEvents = app.????
```

I am searching since couple days but I cannot find the way to collect events only for that app. Maybe we recuperate the events from another way then by app, I am open to any suggestion at this point.

Thank you for any help.

P.S.: Please consider that I am new to use Ruby.

Comment: was my answer helpful @FYB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked [this documentation?](http://cloudfoundryjp.github.io/docs/using/managing-apps/libs/ruby-cfoundry.htm)

I don't have a cloudfoundry account but try running:

`app.methods.grep/event/`

That should give you a list of methods with the word event in them.